# Unable to SSH to a Raspberry Pi Zero from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, ssh, raspberrypi

I am trying to ssh into my new Raspberry Pi Zero w. I have flashed the latest "2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch" on my SD card.
Steps I have followed: https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/raspberry-pi-zerow-headless-wifi-setup.html

After I connect my Pi to power source (I tried connecting it to the laptop using USB connection as well), and try to open ssh, I get following error :

```
lolalol@lolalol-lin:~$ ssh pi@raspberrypi.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: Name or service not known
```

And Pi is not appearing in list of connected devices on my router as well. 
PS: i have copied connection details in WPA config file from this file on my laptop (`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SSID_OF_WIFI`)

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check if RPi gets an IP address, cause if not, ssh is not going to work, no matter how.

Comment: IKR! That is the primary problem, i just dont know how to fix that. I checked my router's DHCP page and Pi is not appearing there so i guess it is not able to connect to router. Am i missing any thing here?

Comment: As said above, you must resolve the IP address/router connection problem to be able to ssh. That problem is with Raspbian, and has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android phone, there is a handy app called "Net Analyzer" that I like to use to help me find out if a device connected to the LAN and what its IP addy is and if it has an mDNS name (e.g. raspberrypi.local).

In "Net ANalyzer" there is a tool called "LAN Scan" that scans the LAN and reports IP addy, MAC addys, mDNS Name, etc.

If you have an IP addy that you think is the Pi Zero, you can type in

ssh root@192.168.1.123

for example. If that doesn't work then you pry need to double check your WiFi settings on the uSD card.

If you are able to login into the Pi Zero W via IP addy but not via mDNS name, and if you are using a PC to get raspberrypi.local, you will need to install bonjour onto it. Here is what I eventually found that worked.
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_US

I still do not know if Android has any mDNS tool available, but "Net Analyzer" comes to the rescue for that issue.